# Bluetooth startDiscovery stops working

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have an Android app that scans BT devices every 60sec. I'm testing the same app in three equal devices (Moto X Play, 2 with Lollipop and 1 with Marshmallow), however, in one of the Lollipop mobiles the startDiscovery() method stops detecting devices after a few minutes of functioning correctly. I know that because this debug line is being printed every minute: `"Bluetooth is starting a new discovery"` and neither the `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` or `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` events are received

This is the code inside the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver in charge of listenning to BT events:

```
       if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN)) {

                if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter is not present");
                } else if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    //Bluetooth is off
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter is turned off...");
                }else{
                    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter was discovering, cancelling...");
                        if(bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter cancelled a previous discovery");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter could not cancel a previous discovery");
                        }
                    }

                    if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter is starting a new discovery");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth adapter error on starting a new discovery");
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am registering my BT actions like this in the onCreate method of my service:

```
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Bluetooth.ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(bluetoothMonitor, filter);

        Intent backgroundService = new Intent(ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN);
        bluetoothScan = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, backgroundService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Very strangely, sometimes I get this weird output in my logcat:

```
03-01 16:57:31.768 1103-1300/? V/AlarmManager: sending alarm {16adb330 type 0 *walarm*:ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN}
03-01 16:57:31.788 21145-21145/? D/AWARE::Bluetooth: Bluetooth is starting a new discovery
03-01 16:57:31.802 1103-1103/? V/AlarmManager: done {16adb330, *walarm*:ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN} [40ms]
03-01 17:00:31.852 1103-1300/? V/AlarmManager: sending alarm {16adb330 type 0 *walarm*:ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN}
03-01 17:00:31.879 21145-21145/? D/AWARE::Bluetooth: Bluetooth is starting a new discovery
03-01 17:00:31.884 1103-1103/? V/AlarmManager: done {16adb330, *walarm*:ACTION_AWARE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_SCAN} [40ms]
03-01 17:00:46.187 3573-3630/? D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 80:E4:DA:71:B5:13
03-01 17:00:46.189 3573-3630/? D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 80:E4:DA:71:BC:69
03-01 17:00:46.191 3573-3630/? D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 80:E4:DA:71:B4:C8
03-01 17:00:46.193 3573-3630/? D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 80:E4:DA:71:A4:61
03-01 18:58:34.548 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
03-01 18:58:37.823 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
03-01 18:58:37.826 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
03-01 18:58:40.375 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
03-01 18:58:44.408 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
03-01 18:58:44.411 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
03-01 18:58:44.579 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
03-01 18:58:46.589 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
03-01 18:58:46.591 2017-10585/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Yeah, it was a bug in Android 5 related to the firmware of the Moto X Play. I ended up upgrading to 6